# jquery to count number of rows returned

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `Jquery` in my MVC View page

```
$(function () {
    $('#SelectedProductId').change(function () {
    var selectedProduct = $('#SelectedProductId option:selected').val();
    if (selectedProduct == null || selectedProduct == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    $('#pleaseWaitMessage').dialog("open");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyProducts.aspx/GetProducts",
        data: { ProdId: selectedProduct },
        timeout: 8000,
        success: function (data) {
            var content = $(data);
            $('#productParameters').html(content);
            $('#pleaseWaitMessage').dialog("close");
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#pleaseWaitMessage').dialog("close");
            $('#systemError').dialog("open");
        }
    });
});
```

});

This works perfectly fine, it returns the list of products and displays them on the page based on the option selected from a drop down list.

What I want to try and do is extend this a little so on `success` it will also check the number of items that have been returned, that way I can try and enable / disable options.  So if it returned 0 I would disable the Buy button from the page, and if it was greater than 0 it should enable it.

I've tried using `content.count >0` but when I first the count into an `alert` it says 34 when I'm really expected 1 (there is only 1 row).

Is there any easy way to check how many rows have been returned, in the `jquery` above, and then perform another action?

Edit:
The data is obtained through the call to my Controller -> Data Access Layer class -> SQL, there are no web services.

Edit2:
On the recommendation of @Roberto Linares my full script looks as follows with the document ready feature

```
$(function () {
    $('#SelectedProductId').change(function () {
    var selectedProduct = $('#SelectedProductId option:selected').val();
    if (selectedProduct == null || selectedProduct == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    $('#pleaseWaitMessage').dialog("open");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyProducts.aspx/GetProducts",
        data: { ProdId: selectedProduct },
        timeout: 8000,
        success: function (data) {
            var content = $(data);
            $('#productParameters').html(content);
            $('#pleaseWaitMessage').dialog("close");
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#pleaseWaitMessage').dialog("close");
            $('#systemError').dialog("open");
        }
    });
});
```

});

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SelectedProductId').change(function () {
        var selectedProduct = $('#SelectedProductId option:selected').val();
        if (selectedProduct == null || selectedpProduct == -1) {
            return false;
        }
        alert($('#productParameters>table>tbody>tr').count);
    });
});
```

My View page contains

```
<div>
    <div id="tableHolder">
        <table id="productList">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>product</th>
                    <th>Date From</th>
                    <th>Date To</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="productParameters"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why dont you send the numbers of rows in that response from the server?

Comment: Looks like you're currently just returning HTML? A JSON object that had both the count and the new HTML content as properties would be one way. Alternatively you can count the number of rows (are they actual `<tr>` elements?) inside of `#productParameters` after updating the content. If you show us an example of what `data` is going to be (i.e. what your server code sends as the response body) it would help a huge amount.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return bot the content and the count on success.

E.g. return an object that has OriginalContent and ContentCount (an int)

and then in your js

```
var count= data.ContentCount ;
var content = $(data.OriginalContent);
$('#productParameters').html(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to return the count of rows as an extra value in your Ajax Response but since you are just returning raw HTML instead of json or any other structure data, you could count the number of HTML elements inserted after you do the  `$('#productParameters').html(content);`.

Assuming you are inserting a list of `<tr>` elements inside a `<table>`, you could count them after inserting them with something like `$('#productParmeters>table>tbody>tr').length`

Comment: I rather like the idea of counting the TRs as this seems simple.   Where would be the best place to put that code in the jquery I've listed?  I tried just after $('#productParameters').html(content); but it returned 0 (I can only gather this is because it counted before the page finished rendering).

Comment: @MattR if the page hasn't finished rendering then the code should go inside a `$(document).ready(function(){ });`. Also check if the traverse query is correct. I was just guessing the HTML you were returning from the Ajax call.

Comment: I've tried that and it still is returning 0.  I've added the code to the original post on the off chance you spot where I am going wrong.

Comment: It won't let me further edit the above comment.  It also still seems to display the alert prior to the call to SQL which i guess would explain the 0 results, so (document).reader doesn't seem to be working.  As I say I've put the code on the bottom of the main post.

Comment: @MattR In the new code you posted, I see that `productParameters` is the id of your `<tbody>` element, not your `<table>` element so the traverse query in your alert is wrong. It should be `alert($('#productParameters>tr').count);`

Comment: I've gave that a shot but I still seem to be having trouble.  It fires the alert before the table has (visibily at least) displayed the rows, so the result is zero.     `$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#productParameters>tr').change(function () {
            alert($('#productParameters>tr').length);
        });
    });`

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this problem in slightly different way -

Lets take a product model -

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

And there is a controller action which will return List of Products as Json result -

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Toyota", Quantity = 10 });
        products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Merc", Quantity = 20 });
        products.Add(new Product() { Name = "BMW", Quantity = 30 });

        return new JsonResult() { Data = products, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

And on the View, I use JQuery Templates to render all the products. Advantage of this templating approach is that there is no need for our controller action to return html response, It can simply return list of products. So the count can be calculated using `data.length` and at the same time dynamic binding of data can be achieved using templating.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script id="productsTmpl" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr>
        <th>${Name}</th>
        <th>${Quantity}</th>
    </tr>
</script>

<table id="tblProducts">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr></tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="click" id="click" />

<div id="count"></div>
```

Not the JQuery function would be -

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('#click').click(function (e) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetProducts")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                $("#count").html(data.length);
                $("#productsTmpl").tmpl(data).appendTo("#tblProducts");
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
            });                
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the output when we click on the button would be -

[image]